# How to disable error highlighting in dart vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I would like to disable the red squiggly line that appears below the text when you type something wrong or you have incorrect syntax. I'm on vscode and I'm running a flutter app written in dart. How do I disable that error highlighting?

Comment: perhaps uninstall the related extension and install the official one, I don't have code checker on my side?

Comment: You can disable it in the Dart/Flutter plugin settings. But why would you want to? Those squiggly lines are there to show you errors that would prevent your app from building and running. To be able to see them is to be able to know where the errors are in your code without having to compile your program, have it fail, and track down the reasons manually. And if you are producing so many errors that the squiggly lines are getting intrusive and annoying, then that is incentive to improve your own skills.